# Is it possible to WCF service integration on MAUI framework and how?

Tags: wcf, maui, wcf-binding, wcf-ria-services, maui-windows

Is it possible to WCF service integration on MAUI framework?

I need to implement login page on MAUI through integrate WCF Service

Do you have any reference link regarding this?

I am trying to integrate WCF login service in my MAUI application

I expecting, How can i integrate WCF service on my MAUI application?

Comment: _"Is it possible to WCF service integration on MAUI framework?"_ - yes, with some pain.

Comment: _"I need to implement login page on MAUI through integrate WCF Service. Do you have any reference link regarding this?"_ - No, I don't. No such reference is necessary: making a call to a WCF service is just like any other web-service: get a service client (be it hand-written or auto-generated) and call its `LoginAsync` method or whatever-have-you from an appropriate event-handler, command-method, or reducer-middleware, and get the login-result and _do something_ with it.

Comment: Start here: [Consume a REST-based web service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/data-cloud/rest).

Comment: I think this document can help you[Invoke platform code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/invoke-platform-code)